# Connection from ASP.NET to Derby

Tags: asp.net, connection, database-connection, derby, asp.net-webpages

It seems connecting to a Derby database from ASP.NET is unconventional, but it seems like it should be possible.

The project is a web page application.

I've got a web.config file using:

```
<add name="DerbyConnectionString"
         connectionString="server=localhost:1527;
         database=Test;
         uid=username;
         password=password"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and the .cshtml using:

```
    @{
        var db = Database.Open("DerbyConnectionString");
        var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Test";
    }

   <table> 
        <tr>
            <td>
                SQL Server Instance  
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th> 
            <th>Color</th> 
        </tr>
        @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
        {
            <tr> 
                <td>@row.indext</td> 
                <td>@row.Color</td> 
            </tr> 
        }
    </table>
```

I've gotten this format to work with Oracle and SQL Server, but there seems to be very little information for Derby.  The example I found was using the SqlClient provider, but its returning a error:
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

Which makes senses as we're telling it to look for an SQL Server that doesn't exist.

Any help towards establish a derby connection in this format is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible what you are trying to do, are you using a dedicated library to connect to it? How you're running derbydb?

Comment: Derby's client/server connection uses software contained in derbyclient.jar at the client side. Where did you find any indication that the C# .NET client could talk to Derby?

Comment: @lifeisfoo Derby is being run through Glassfish4.  I was hoping I could use a jdbc / odbc provider to reach the Derby db.

I've seen some examples of MySQL and Postgres doing something similar from the web.config, but I haven't got those to work yet either.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I found this:
https://github.com/tmeers/Derby/blob/master/Derby/Web.config

but I was hoping to avoid calling the file as I want this as a model if the DB is not local on the server.  It seems this is the next step though.

Comment: Unfortunately, Derby (the all-Java database) is really only usable from a Java application, so far as I know. Since you are writing your application in C#, I think you will need to consider a different database to hold your data. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't possible to connect from C# to derby since a communication library doesn't exists.

The project you've linked in the comments is only a project called Derby that isn't related to Apache Derby!

Comment: Well, makes sense why its using an Sqlclient for the provider then.

It feels underwhelming that I can use Java to connect to all my databases, but not ASP.NET.